# "In [x]" и "Out[y]" в исходном коде python

Tags: python

Читая ответы на вопросы на *stackoverflow* по теме *python*'a, иногда встречаю в ответах исходный код довольно странного вида. Вот пример ответа на рандомный вопрос:

```
In [1]: import signal

# Register an handler for the timeout
In [2]: def handler(signum, frame):
   ...:     print "Forever is over!"
   ...:     raise Exception("end of time")
   ...: 

# This function *may* run for an indetermined time...
In [3]: def loop_forever():
   ...:     import time
   ...:     while 1:
   ...:         print "sec"
   ...:         time.sleep(1)
   ...:         
   ...:         

# Register the signal function handler
In [4]: signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
Out[4]: 0
```

Причем, цифра в квадратных скобках в некоторых ответах начинается не с *1*.

**Вопрос:** Откуда берутся эти *In [1]*, *Out [4]*, "...:", зачем оно надо, и почему нумерация в квадратных скобках в разных ответах начинается с разных чисел?

Сам такое никогда не делал и не знаю как сделать.

Comment: это _input_ и _output_ "prompt" с номерами строк/команд в интерактивном Python - iPython

Comment: https://ipython.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это *input* и *output* `prompt` в интерактивном Python - [iPython](http://ipython.org)  или в [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/). Число обозначает порядковый номер строки (команды ввода или вывода).

Пример:

```
In [19]: s = 'a string'

In [20]: s
Out[20]: 'a string'
```

Comment: А я ведь не раз предупреждал, что не стоит упоминать iPython без необходимости :D

Comment: @andreymal, практика показывает, что частые упоминания - это элемент обучения и привыкания... ;-) И вообще, лучше сразу приучать к хорошему и полезному

Comment: В jupyter число обозначает не номер ячейки, а порядок, в котором ячейки были выполнены. Часто получается такое безобразие: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKm8p.png